# Reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: installation, partitioning, re-installation

My hard disk partitioning scheme is like this:

1. 30 GB root partition (extended) (/)
2. 1.0 GB swap space (extended)
3. 289 GB home partition (extended) (/home)

I had made such a partitioning scheme assuming that I could perform a full re-install without disturbing my data. Now if I am to do it (re-install Ubuntu), how should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose manual partitioning, assign the partitions as you stated above, and don't tick the format box on /home.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your data is in /home, you should be able to redo an installation, as long as you choose the manual partitioning, and set the same partition as /home, and the two others for / and swap.

But, as for any other OS-related operation,make a full backup of all your data files. You never know what may happen to your files, and if you reformat your data partition by mistake, you will be happy to have a full backup first.