# Reinstalling ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I have Ubuntu 11.10 64bit, and due to some installations via terminal, I lost many files in libc, and I can't repair, so, I need to reinstall Ubuntu 11.10. Please suggest an easy way to get Ubuntu 11.10 re-installed.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You may refer to this post. http://askubuntu.com/a/152902/71205

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to install ubuntu from a usb or cd, you can download the iso from here [ubuntu 11.10 64bits](http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso), burn the iso to a cd or usb, boot your computer with the cd or usb and install.

Comment: but the screen gets terminated while installing ubuntu from cd. Please suggestthe answer

Comment: If the cd is an oficial one if note the iso file probaly it wasn't buurn fully on the cd. Try to burn it in a new cd

Comment: If you burn it in a new cd it dosn't work try to burn it in a usb in windows an osX you can use deamon tools which is free for personal use this link to http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads use DAEMON Tools Lite.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the answer here (correct) you might want to keep your home files and install Ubuntu on top of that.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21075/reinstalling-ubuntu) you can find the most basic solution. Ask further if you need more help.